# Creating a Column for a VIEW Table and paste value of '1' for all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

My first question is what VIEW schema is actually used for? Whats the purpose? and does the results update automatically if something has been added or removed or altered within the tables that are linked to the VIEW?

And this is my question about some code:

I have this code here that creates a VIEW TABLE:

```
CREATE VIEW innerb_comma AS
SELECT CONCAT(Pcode, ',') AS Pcode,
       CONCAT(Brand, ',') AS Brand,
       CONCAT(descr, ',') AS descr,
       CONCAT(Size, ',') AS Size,
       Barcode AS Barcode
FROM innerb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wms WHERE barcode = innerb.barcode) 
  AND Pcode like '%102';
```

Id like to insert a new column in there called `Quantity` and just paste a number `1` for every single row available.

Comment: I don't think I can improve on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - just add 1 as quantity in select list

```
CREATE VIEW innerb_comma AS
SELECT CONCAT(Pcode, ',') AS Pcode,
       CONCAT(Brand, ',') AS Brand,
       CONCAT(descr, ',') AS descr,
       CONCAT(Size, ',') AS Size,
       Barcode AS Barcode, 1 as quantity
FROM innerb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wms WHERE barcode = innerb.barcode) 
  AND Pcode like '%102'
```

Comment: Perfect just what I needed!

Comment: I will soon as the time expires haha